# Motors not working with a motor Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield

Got a Duratech motor shield today, and I'm wondering why my motors do not run. Appreciate any help. The code I am using is the Adafruit sample code, Motorparty. The servos work however the motors do not.

Here is a photo of my setup, code is below:

[image: Setup]

```
/* 
This is a test sketch for the Adafruit assembled Motor Shield for Arduino v2
It won't work with v1.x motor shields! Only for the v2's with built in PWM
control

For use with the Adafruit Motor Shield v2 
---->   http://www.adafruit.com/products/1438

This sketch creates a fun motor party on your desk *whiirrr*
Connect a unipolar/bipolar stepper to M3/M4
Connect a DC motor to M1
Connect a hobby servo to SERVO1
*/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h> 
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>

// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(); 
// Or, create it with a different I2C address (say for stacking)
// Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(0x61); 

// Connect a stepper motor with 200 steps per revolution (1.8 degree)
// to motor port #2 (M3 and M4)
Adafruit_StepperMotor *myStepper = AFMS.getStepper(200, 2);
// And connect a DC motor to port M1
Adafruit_DCMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getMotor(3);

// We'll also test out the built in Arduino Servo library
Servo servo1;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  Serial.println("MMMMotor party!");

  AFMS.begin();  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz
  //AFMS.begin(1000);  // OR with a different frequency, say 1KHz
  
  // Attach a servo to pin #10
  servo1.attach(10);
   
  // turn on motor M1
  myMotor->setSpeed(200);
  myMotor->run(RELEASE);
  
  // setup the stepper
  myStepper->setSpeed(10);  // 10 rpm   
}

int i;
void loop() {
  myMotor->run(FORWARD);
  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    servo1.write(map(i, 0, 255, 0, 180));
    myMotor->setSpeed(i);  
    myStepper->step(1, FORWARD, INTERLEAVE);
    delay(3);
 }
 
 for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    servo1.write(map(i, 0, 255, 0, 180));
    myMotor->setSpeed(i);  
    myStepper->step(1, BACKWARD, INTERLEAVE);
    delay(3);
 }
 
  myMotor->run(BACKWARD);
  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    servo1.write(map(i, 0, 255, 0, 180));
    myMotor->setSpeed(i);  
    myStepper->step(1, FORWARD, DOUBLE);
    delay(3);
 }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    servo1.write(map(i, 0, 255, 0, 180));
    myMotor->setSpeed(i);  
    myStepper->step(1, BACKWARD, DOUBLE);
    delay(3);
 }
}
```

Comment: You can try to replace the motor with an LED and a resistor. This way you can check, if there is at least something coming out (the LED will only light up in one drive direction). Also you can try measuring the voltage with a multimeter. From the picture I cannot really see, how everything is connected. Please provide a schematic or wiring diagram